# Google Sheets - What is the formula that allows me to have search criteria instead of search_key for LOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a formula that I could use in a google sheet.
I am looking for a first cell in a column that is negative value.

I thought [LOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) was perfect for this task. It lets me search for a cell in a range and return the result from different column with same row that formula found.

However, I realized that search_key parameter for this formula has to be solid entry.

Is there any formula in Google Sheet that allows me to search the way I want?

To illustrate, I would like to automatically detect the following image's orange cell.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Index` function with `Match` function. Check if the value is less than 0 and return its index.

Here is the formula:

```
INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:B6<0,0,1),0))
```

Where 'A2:A6' is the month cell range and 'B2:B6' is the value cell range. Check [this google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DfC71PX0afTAKHu9Wl4F5UCgpZChvxAOEe-upuWrLKI/edit?usp=sharing) I've created.

#### Reference:

- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472)

Comment: That did the job. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped. :)